# Call Oracle pl/sql function through java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I need to write a Java stored procedure that can call an oracle PL/SQL function from the calling Oracle instance.

My Java stored procedure method calls the following Java method

```
private void WriteToDB(String action, String timestamp, String filename) {
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        try{
            String serverIP = "xx.xx.xx";
            String portNumber = "yyyy";
            String instanceName = "instance1";
            String username = "user1";
            String password = "password1";
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverIP + ":" + portNumber + ":" + instanceName;
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);


            String call = "{ call PACKAGE1.FUNCTION1(?, ?, ?) }";
                          cstmt = connection.prepareCall(call);
                          cstmt.setQueryTimeout(1800);
                          cstmt.setString(1, action);
                          cstmt.setString(2, timestamp);
                          cstmt.setString(3, filename);                      
                          cstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            WriteEventToLogFile(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            if (cstmt != null){
                cstmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the code from my Netbeans IDE it runs properly and the PL/SQL function gets executed (Pl/SQL function inserts a record to a table). But when I load the jar to oracle and run the stored procedure in Oracle the method seems to execute without any exceptions but no records gets inserted to the table, which makes me think that the PL/SQL function was not executed.

Also my question is there any way to make a create a Connection object to the calling oracle instance without using the URL (Which means my ip, port nad instance name must be provided).

Is using the OracleDriver.getDefaultConnection() possible for this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by loading the jar to oracle?

Comment: using sys.dbms_java.loadjava method can load my jar to oracle and call any static Java method from PL/sql. need to write a Pl#sql wrapper funtion to call the relevent java method as follows  procedure Test_Thread
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'NTO.Excel.ExcelFunctions.TestThread()';

Comment: Does your stored procedure perform a COMMIT after the INSERT? If not, try putting one in (for debugging only) and see if your data is inserted. Also, in case of an exception, you use WriteEventToDb() - are you sure this procedure works?

Comment: yes that method name is misleading, sorry, only writes to a logfile not the DB as the neame specifies and no exceptions are logged to the file.

Comment: There are two different things here. One is calling store procedure or function from java and other thing is calling java program from PL/SQL. If stand-alone jar is working fine, then the problem is with PL/SQL block. If you need java capability in your PL/SQL, use SQLJ which offers the java functionality and easy way to access database with SQL.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I tried adding a Commit call in the java method and also used the OracleDriver.defaultConnection() and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a connection.close() or connection.commit().  You might want to add those in.  In your IDE it worked because the main program terminated and so jvm execute the finalize method on your Driver and it close the connection for you.  In the case you execute on the "server" (wherever that is) it isn't releasing the connection.  If you check the database session, it probably still hanging around smoking...

Answer (score 0):

you can call function like this

> String call = "{ SELECT PACKAGE1.FUNCTION1(?, ?, ?) FROM DUAL }";